# Inline images in HTML without base64

Tags: javascript, html, image, web

Alright so i know i can convert an image into base64 and then add that to my html. The problem with base64 is that the data it produces is, in my case, 33% larger than my png image file, which is a maximum compressed 300KB css sprite.

Is there any way to transmit the image data without using base64 and then assemble it into an image on the client?

I was thinking of transmitting the hex image data, and then using javascript to convert it to base64. Seems possible, but incredibly redundant since that would be instantly decoded back from base64 just to be displayed.

Any ideas?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hex is much worse than bas64, it will be 100% larger than the original file (an 8-bit byte is two hex characters).

Answer (score 0):

I've just done some testing to check file sizes, and I've found that there is no significant difference.

sizeof(gzip(index.html + sprite.png)) = 301KB

sizeof(gzip(index_inline_b64_sprite.html)) = 302KB

Although the base64 text is about 33% larger than the png itself, once gzipped it doesn't seem to make any significant difference.

Once you factor that whatever solution will probably have serious cross-browser and maybe even security issues of strange hex being appended to an html file, in my case it seems a better solution to just stick with base64.

Also thanks Barmar for pointing out that ascii hex in the html would be much larger, i did not realize that at first.